# Extract winning RMSE from optimal R Caret model

Tags: r, r-caret

I create nnet models using the caret package and extract the predicted value using the following code:

```
nnet<-predict(my_model, newdata = my_new_data) 
nnet
[1] -0.1468207
```

I also create the following output whereby I can view the the optimal model parameters as below:

```
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  decay  RMSE        Rsquared   RMSE SD      Rsquared SD
  10    0.001  0.01867841  0.4789708  0.002538599  0.12778927 
  10    0.100  0.02349088  0.1233067  0.001859455  0.10188046 
  12    0.001  0.01826047  0.5059824  0.002630588  0.12962511 
  12    0.100  0.02348553  0.1238252  0.001890646  0.09851303 
  15    0.001  0.01795350  0.5289120  0.003021449  0.13908835 
  15    0.100  0.02318972  0.1429446  0.001932714  0.11156927 

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were size = 15 and decay = 0.001.
```

My question is how can I create a variable which just contains the optimal RMSE from the final model? (Instead of having to manually check the output.)

Eg. Something along these lines:

```
Model_RMSE<-nnet$finalModelRMSE
Model_RMSE
[1] 0.01795350
```

Thank you

*Update
Thanks @SamThomas that's it. I actually wanted just the RMSE from the 'winning/optimum' used model so I just wrapped your suggestion in a min() as below.

```
>nnet$results["RMSE"]
        RMSE
1 0.01867841
2 0.02349088
3 0.01826047
4 0.02348553
5 0.01795350
6 0.02318972

>min(nnet$results["RMSE"])
[1] 0.0179535
```

Comment: How about `nnet$results["RMSE"]`. If that doesn't work, then a reproducible example would be helpful (and is good practice in any case)

Comment: Thanks very much Sam Thomas. Update above. Point taken about the reproducible example too

Answer (score 7):

There is already a function to do just this called `getTrainPerf`.

Max

Comment: Great, thanks Max. `> getTrainPerf(nnetFit)
   TrainRMSE TrainRsquared method
1 0.01749052     0.5415966   nnet`

Answer (score 0):

Glad the comment helped.  If you want the full row from the results, this might be useful.

```
nnet$results[which.min(nnet$results[, "RMSE"]), ]
```

Comment: That looks useful but I couldn't get it to work; '> nnet$results[which.min(nnet$results["RMSE"]), ]
Error in which.min(nnet$results["RMSE"]) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double''

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited if you're interested in trying again.  `nnet$results` is a data.frame.  Therefore `nnet$results[, "RMSE"]` should return the column named `RMSE`

Comment: Thanks, this gave me `[1] 0.01817819 0.02303919 0.01784826 0.02292240 0.01749456 0.02260340`. I really just needed the lowest chosen value but good to know